# Cordova build failing for android

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

While generating app for  Cordova-android  using Cordova compile android command I am getting following error and not able proceed .

```
Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `':app:processDebugResources'`.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/shrivastavas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d291a6f185053cd23b616e4ab375bb6e/transformed/appcompat-1.3.1/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

```
 ERROR:/Users/shrivastavas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d291a6f185053cd23b616e4ab375bb6e/transformed/appcompat-1.3.1/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
     
 ERROR:/Users/shrivastavas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/09314801a92bc2d84a1fe4a156efb7a9/transformed/core-1.5.0/res/values/values.xml:152:5-183:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
     
 ERROR:/Users/shrivastavas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/09314801a92bc2d84a1fe4a156efb7a9/transformed/core-1.5.0/res/values/values.xml:152:5-183:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
     
 ERROR:/Users/shrivastavas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d291a6f185053cd23b616e4ab375bb6e/transformed/appcompat-1.3.1/res/values/values.xml:2797:5-2820:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
```

I tried couple of option received in stack flow but didn't able to solve it.

Comment: Post your config/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I face these types of bug when I update google material dependency.
I solve this simply replace with this version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Comment: Hi Faisal thanks for your reply can you please help me where to put this code.

Comment: in build.gradle(app) file inside dependencies {}

Comment: hi I tried this option but still the build failed.

Comment: You should try just upgrading [:1.6.1] or downgrading the version.